# Different types of DC Motor with PIC + Bluetooth

Tags: dc-motor

I have an issue with DC motor and Bluetooth.
I'm using PIC PIC18F, TIP 31 NPN transistor as motor driver and 4 x AA rechargeable battery. Each battery is about 1500mAh.
The board has 2 modes, 1.Simple Run and 2.Bluetooh

I have 3 motors and all are in good condition:

1. Motor A: 2.1 mAh
2. Motor B: 20 mAh
3. Motor C: 70 mAh

In "Simple Run" mode, the 3 motors run without an issue.
But when in "Bluetooth" mode with PWM, Motor B had difficulty in running and Motor C had a slight issue. Motor A is perfectly fine.
I have an android app to control the motor using bluetooh.

It looks like the current issue. But I already use 1500mAh battery.Somehow Motor C is run better than Motor B.

What may be the issue?

It looks like the Motor draw away the current from Bluetooth module and the microprocessor. This cause the signal send from the Android App break.

Or could it be the current from the motor fall back / kick back to the board?

Should I should Motor Driver IC instead of using TIP 31?

[image]

Comment: Upload the image to http://imgur.com/ and give us a link and we can add the image to your post

Comment: Post a link to image and I'll put it in your post.

Comment: @user4185 - Here's an upvote to get you closer to the required privileges.  Kellenjb and AndrejaKo, if you'd just upvoted him, he'd have it by now...

Comment: Thanks for the supports guys. I just uploaded my schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Driving the PIC, Bluetooth and the motor from the same battery is asking for problems. Try using a separate supply for the motor.

Comment: Yes, you could be right. But on Arduino board, it seems ok when using 9v battery to run bluetooth, mcu and motor.

Comment: The arduino uses a different microcontroller, with a different fab-house. Noise sensitivity between the two may be wildly different. Also, are you running the motors straight off the battery on the arduino? If so you are getting some noise rejection from the onboard voltage regulator.

Comment: Does motor driver IC help the noise issue?